Kakbhushandi's different versions of epics
How can there be multiple version, with different outcomes like, Pandavs losing etc. If that was the case, how would there be yug parivartan? Plus, doesn't it go against that time is helix?

There is no different outcomes. Rama wins each time and Pandavas win each time. However certain story elements would be different in each Kalpa. That's it.
